# 複数の処理をfor文で一つのコードにまとめる方法はありますか？

Tags: python

画像のようにdf1~12 target_list1~12　まで増えるコードがあるのですが
for文で一つにまとめたいと考えています。

見た目が悪いので何かいい方法はないでしょうか？

[image: 複数の変数]

Answer (score 2):

[辞書型](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#mapping-types-dict)の利用がスタンダートです。
そのほかに[リスト型](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#lists)もよく利用されます。

**辞書型のサンプルコード**

```
dic = {}
for i in range(1, 13):
    dic[i] = f'ゾーン名 in @target_list{i}'

print(dic[1])   # ゾーン名 in @target_list1
print(dic[12])  # ゾーン名 in @target_list12
```

Answer (score 0):

`df` が Pandas のデータフレームだとすれば、`target_list1` ~ `target_list12` をリストのリストにして list comprehension で抽出する方法もあるかと思います。(出力はデータフレームのリストになります)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ゾーン名': ['d', 'i', 'b', 'f', 'a', 'g', 'e', 'c', 'h']})

target_list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
target_list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
target_list3 = ['g', 'h', 'i']
target_list = [target_list1, target_list2, target_list3]

#
dfs = [df.query('ゾーン名 in @target').reset_index(drop=True) for target in target_list]
print(f'dfs[0] =\n{dfs[0]}')
print(f'dfs[1] =\n{dfs[1]}')
print(f'dfs[2] =\n{dfs[2]}')

# dfs[0] =
#    ゾーン名
# 0        b
# 1        a
# 2        c
# 
# dfs[1] =
#    ゾーン名
# 0        d
# 1        f
# 2        e
# 
# dfs[2] =
#    ゾーン名
# 0        i
# 1        g
# 2        h
```